# How to use compiler version 0.4.17?

Tags: solidity

I am using [solidity extension by Juan Blanco](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
    
contract Inbox
{
    string public message;
        
    constructor(string initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }
        
    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

I get the error message "Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.4+commit.3f05b770.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version"

I am getting too many error messages / warnings if I do `pragma solidity >=0.4.17;` so I prefer 0.4.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the compiler version within `VSCode` through the command palette:

> Menu->View->Command Palette->Solidity: Change workspace compiler
> version (Remote)

or

> Menu->View->Command Palette->Solidity: Change global compiler version
> (Remote)

and then, select the compiler version. Sometimes you need to close/open VSCode so that changes are applied.